# How to redirect back if user did not get to page properly in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, redirect

I have a videoWall and a videoWallDetail page.  Currently, this is what I have on the videoWallDetail page:

```
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["video_id"])) Response.Redirect("videoWall.aspx");
```

Users should not enter the detail page this way, but if they know the video id, some might go straight to the detail page by typing it into the url, so this will redirect users back to the videoWall page if they enter a video id in the address bar that is not valid.  My question is how do I redirect back to the videoWall page regardless.  If a user does not click on a link to get to the detail page of a particular video, they get sent back no matter if they enter a valid id into the address bar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are some solutions but most I'm aware of aren't 100%. How much of a war do you want to wage against determined users?

Comment: Why redirect? A 404 seems like a better response to an invalid video_id.

Comment: I don't want a major war, but sometimes videos will change or become inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `Session` on the `videoWall.aspx` page to verify they've come from that page:

**videoWall.aspx**

```
Session["fromVideoWall"] = true;
Response.Redirect("videoWallDetail.aspx?video_id=" + videoId.ToString());
```

**videoWallDetail.aspx**

```
if (Session["fromVideoWall"] != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["video_id"])) Response.Redirect("videoWall.aspx");
Session["fromVideoWall"] = null; //Setting the value back to null ensures the next access must have come from VideoWall.aspx too
```

Answer (score 0):

1 You can use `PostBackUrl` method

And in the target page access to `PreviousPage` and get the data

Link : http://asp-net-example.blogspot.fr/2008/10/postbackurl-example-how-to-submit-page.html

2 You can also rewrite your url with `HttpModule`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not allowed to just enter a known ID into the query string of the videoWallDetail page, then you shouldn't expose that as a query string param. What if I want to bookmark the page, or email someone a URL for them to go straight to? Are those disallowed?

If so, then you need to remove that querystring param. The URL bar should be a perfectly legal way for users to get around. If they can enter a URL to get to a page they shouldn't without a 400 or 500 error, then its YOUR fault as the developer.

Switch over to using a session variable or a form post to confirm they are coming from the proper place if they truly shouldn't be on Page B without having just come from Page A.